# Request AJAX failed

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am making an AJAX request for my form on wordpress, but I have this error in the console:

> > jquery.min.js?ver=5.2.1:2    POST https:/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (echo 0)   send @   jquery.min.js?ver=5.2.1:2
> >     ajax  @   jquery.min.js?ver=5.2.1:2   (anonymous) @   custom.js?ver=1:32
> >     dispatch  @   jquery.min.js?ver=5.2.1:2
> >     v.handle  @   jquery.min.js?ver=5.2.1:2

functions.php :
    
`wp_localize_script(
'jsform',  'phpVars', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php' )  ) );}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mcd_b_js' );`

JS :

````
      if (busy) 
        busy.abort();

      busy = $.ajax({
        url: phpVars.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
          console.log('ok');
        }
      });
    }```
````

Comment: `400` means that server thinks that client did something wrong. Without seeing the serverside, it's not really possible to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Please check phpVars.ajaxurl value. The value should be https://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. you can get this value by